# How to call cef.CreateBrowserSync()

Tags: python, tkinter, cefpython

I'm attempting to use cefpython3 with tkinter and want to make it OOP. Right now I have 3 classes `GUI` which act as the controller (runs tk.Tk()) and controls what page is showing. Next is a `MainPage` class which holds all the pages parts; buttons, labels, and a Browser object. The third class is a BrowserFrame class which is based on the tkinter example on cefpython's tutorial page on GitHub.

I'm getting the error `AssertionError: cefpython.CreateBrowserSync() may only be called on the UI thread`. What is the UI thread? The [documentation](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/api/cefpython.md#createbrowsersync) only explains that it must be called in the UI thread but with no explanation on what the UI thread is.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have called `cef.Initialize()` in a different section of your code from where you are attempting to call `cef.CreateBrowserSync()`

`cef.Initialize()` is what begins the UI thread. [See here](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/api/cefpython.md#initialize)

Comment: I did that on purpose. Is there a way to call them in different places?

Comment: @LukeDev They can be called in different files, but the main Python process loop which contains the  .Initialize() must also call the .CreateBrowserSync() function. If they are in different loops, it will not work. 

I believe we can solve this issue if you provide some example code of your problem.